# Java download corrupts .docx file by adding one character

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, download

My Web application runs Tomcat 8.
A .docx file is correctly uploaded to the server, and is downloaded using the following java code contained within a jsp.

```
File f = new File (Monitor.getPropertyValue("myDir") + (request.getParameter("file")) );

  String filename=request.getParameter("original");
  response.setContentLength((int) f.length());
  response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessing‌​ml.document");

  response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+filename);
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
  ServletOutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();


  int bit = 256;
  int i = 0;
  try {
  while ((bit) >= 0) {
  bit = in.read();
  outs.write(bit);
                     }
       } 
        catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
   outs.flush();
   outs.close();
   in.close();
```

However when I try and open the downloaded file, it is corrupted and Word will not open it (without fixing it first)

When I compared the original file and the downloaded file then I noticed that the downloaded file has one extra character at the end - FF (hex)

If I remove this extra character with a Hex editor, then the file opens fine.

Why is this extra character being added?

Comment: You should not use a `JSP` to download a binary file. Write a servlet instead.

Comment: I know - this is old code that I did not write. Do you think this is the source of the problem, or are you just suggesting good programming practice?

Comment: Best practice. I’ve already did ugly things like this in the past and I learned the hard way to not do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is wrong. After the last actual byte is written, `bit` still contains it, the loop is entered, `in.read()` reads `-1` and writes it out, resulting in the extra `0xFF` (i.e. `-1`) byte.

Change your loop to check what is read before writing it out as follows

```
while((bit = in.read()) != -1) {
    outs.write(bit);
}
```